# How to zoom and scroll map at the same time with OSMDroid

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I work on a project with Google Maps API. I want to move to OSMDroid.

With Google Maps API, when I click on a marker, my map scroll and zoom to it.
I can't reproduce the same effect on OSMDroid.

It seems that `animateTo`  and `zoomTo` cannot be called at the same time.
My map either scroll or zoom, but does not do both.

Do you have any idea or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the new methods in version 6, [zoomToFixing](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocs/osmdroid-android/release/org/osmdroid/views/MapController.html#zoomToFixing-double-int-int-):

```
Point p = mMapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, null);
mMapView.getController().zoomToFixing(zoomLevel, p.x, p.y);
```

Comment: This solution does not center the map on the marker.